# How to generate DML scripts with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, dml

I want to generate DML scripts (insert, delete, update, ....) with Hibernate.

How can I do that? It seems that `SchemaExport` permits schema export only.

I want to dump all the data contained in my database. How to achieve this task?